# Set a fixed width for columns of XWPFTable: Apache POI API

Tags: java, apache

I am using the below function widthCellsAcrossRow to set the width of columns in a XWPFTable. It seems that the column width gets extended when the data seems to be more than the width defined. 
So is there any way to avoid this width extension, if data length is more to accomodate in that width, a word wrap would do?

```
static void widthCellsAcrossRow (XWPFTable table, int rowNum, int colNum, int width) {
        XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum);
        if (cell.getCTTc().getTcPr() == null)
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
        if (cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcW()==null)
            cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewTcW();
        cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf((long) width));
}
```

I'm invoking the above function as below:

```
for (int i=0;i<(tableChipDataLayoutSpecification1.getNumberOfRows());i++) {
    widthCellsAcrossRow(tableChipDataLayoutSpecification1, i, 0, 700);
    widthCellsAcrossRow(tableChipDataLayoutSpecification1, i, 1, 600);
    widthCellsAcrossRow(tableChipDataLayoutSpecification1, i, 2, 6000);
    widthCellsAcrossRow(tableChipDataLayoutSpecification1, i, 3, 700);
    widthCellsAcrossRow(tableChipDataLayoutSpecification1, i, 4, 700);
    widthCellsAcrossRow(tableChipDataLayoutSpecification1, i, 5, 700);
    widthCellsAcrossRow(tableChipDataLayoutSpecification1, i, 6, 600);
}
```

where tableChipDataLayoutSpecification1 is a XWPFTable.
Many thanks in advance.